# Where to put declaration in phd thesis?

Tags: thesis

I am doing my PhD in an europe university and they have almost no requirements about the thesis formatting. I choosed the following outline:

1. Titlepage
2. Acknowledgment
3. Content
4. Chapter 1 - Chapter 3
5. Summary
6. Bibliography
7. Declaration

Now I wonder, is there a commen position for the declaration page (such as the first page after the title page or so?).

My declaration pages states that I did the work by myself and have not handed in the dissertation elsewhere.

I am a bit surprised, because in all so far viewed phd thesis I didn't find a declaration at all. Is this often taken out befor the thesis is published online?

Comment: What's the content of the declaration page? (And why do you put the abstract *after* the content?)

Comment: What does your adviser think? We don't know what a "declaration" is in this context. @StephanKolassa I imagine OP means "Table of contents"

Comment: Mine comes right after the title page, but I checked my (UK) university regulations and they also don't specify where it should be.

Comment: My (UK) university regulations stipulated that it should come after any dedication or acknowledgements, but before the table of contents.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I have added a description of the declaration page. I didnt mean abstract but rather a summary, I changed that too.

Comment: _they have almost no requirements about the thesis_, but you are not the first PhD student in that university, right? I would suggest you to go to the university library and check  how other PhD students in the past wrote their theses. Also check this with your advisor.

Answer (score 3):

Not every university demands such a declaration (e.g., stating that it is your own work, and all external sources have been properly cited, referenced, and acknowledged). I had one in my master thesis, but not in my PhD thesis (performed at a different university). Just follow the university rules. If they demand a declaration, then typically there is a verbatim text that you have to put in.

If your university does not prescribe where it should come, but does demand that you have a declaration, then you are free to put it anywhere. It is, however, wise to follow the convention of your university, and put it where others have put it. As @scaaahu indicated, you can go to the library and look what others did.

(Btw, I have seen it typically somewhere at the beginning.)